# How can i integrate zooz payment gateway using zooz ios sdk into xamarin ios app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, zooz

How can i integrate zooz payment gateway using ZOOZ IOS SDK.i have a xamarin based ios native app in which i need to integrate payment gateway using ios sdk.

documents provided by zooz for integrating zooz is not providing much help in how to integrate it for  xamarin ios code. please help me in integrating zooz ios sdk with process i need to follow.

Comment: hi, i am in a similar situation. what did you do for payment gateway integration?

Answer (score 1):

Without a bit more detail, it's hard to reply directly with guidance to your question, however if you go to the following link it has a step-by-step guide on how to consume third party libraries with Xamarin:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/

Hope that helps,

Jonathan